# Prove $\sqrt{a^2 + ab + b^2} + \sqrt{b^2 + bc + c^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + ac + a^2} \ge \sqrt{3}(a + b + c)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Prove $\sqrt{a^2 + ab + b^2} + \sqrt{b^2 + bc + c^2}  + \sqrt{c^2 + ac + a^2} \ge \sqrt{3}(a + b + c)$

So, using AM-GM, or just pop out squares under square roots we can show:
$$\sqrt{a^2 + ab + b^2} + \sqrt{b^2 + bc + c^2}  + \sqrt{c^2 + ac + a^2} \ge \sqrt{3}(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca}),$$
i.e. we need next to show that $(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca}) \ge (a + b + c)$, but i don't know how to do it.

Any help appreciated

Comment: $a,b,c$ can be assumed to be positive reals. If some of them are $0$, then the inequality will reduce to fewer variables and will be easy. If they are negative then all of them must be negative, in which case it's trivially true. So WLOG assume they are positive and see my geometric solution.

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya, yes, they are positive, i thought it is obviosly. But i can manually write it to post

Comment: $(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca}) \ge (a + b + c)$ is not true. The reverse inequality is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Minkowski (triangle inequality) $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}b^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\left(\sum_{cyc}\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\left(\sum_{cyc}b\right)^2}=\sqrt3(a+b+c).$$

Comment: Minkowski! Sure, i've forgotten about this remarkable inequality, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a point $O$ and the lines $OA$, $OB$, $OC$ of lengths $a,b,c$ respectively such that $\angle AOB=\angle BOC= \angle COA=120^°$. Consider the triangle $\Delta ABC$. using **cosine rule** you can see that the side lengths of that triangle are $\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2},\sqrt{b^2+bc+c^2},\sqrt{c^2+ca+a^2}$.

By definition $O$ is the Fermat point of $\Delta ABC$. See the properties of Fermat point and solve this geometric inequality.

Comment: ok, i've read about Fermat point and that this point can be found with using Lagrange multipliers. But unfortunately, i can't use any derivative method. Can it be other way? Or maybe you suggested other way with this Fermat point?

Comment: Draw a figure of the triangle like I said. Then try.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Fermat_point see this link

Comment: i can't understand, what do you suppose me to do, sorry. In this link there are only proofs, that found point is Fermat point, no properties. Anyways i tried use just triangle inequality for every side in the constructed triangle and got this: $2(a + b + c) \le \sum_{all} \sqrt{a_i^2 + a_ib_i + b_i^2}$, which is almost what i need. But not exactly:)

Comment: hm, ok. But is this just solid way to proof this? I mean, from begin we constructed a triangle with equal angles ($120^\circ$). Now we say that by construction point $O$ is being Fermat point. Then we just use triangle inequality to prove main problem. Then for what we noted that $O$ is Fermat point?

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya What happens if one of angles of the triangle is greater than $120^{\circ}$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg according to my construction $\angle AOB=\angle BOC= \angle COA=120^°$. Hence $\angle OAB+\angle OBA=60^°, \angle OAC+\angle OCA=60^°, \angle OBC+\angle OCB=60^°$. So no angle of $\Delta ABC$ will exceed $120^°$.

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya If $\measuredangle ABC>120^{\circ}$ so your point $O$ just does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg please notice that the point $O$ constructs the triangle $\Delta ABC$. So the existence of $O$ precedes the existence of $\Delta ABC$. The point $O$ determines the triangle.

Comment: @Shubhrajit Bhattacharya Yes, I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome 

Answer (score 2):

The problem has appeared here various times and maybe elsewhere too for sure. The key to this is to observe the relationship between: $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$ and $a^2+ab+b^2 \ge \dfrac{3(a+b)^2}{4}$. They are equivalent. Using the latter but taking the square root first $3$ times for $(a,b), (b,c),(c,a)$ and add up, yielding the result.

Comment: I searched carefully double-posts, but found nothing, even in looking similar problems. Thanks for your method anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use SOS here:

$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}-\sqrt3(a+b+c)=\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}-\frac{\sqrt3(a+b)}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4(a^2+ab+b^2)-3(a+b)^2}{2\left(2\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}+\sqrt3(a+b)\right)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{2\left(2\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}+\sqrt3(a+b)\right)}\geq0.$$